# Python "Cloud Computing" service?

Tags: python, kotlin, cloud

I'm currently working on a project which allows me to generate complex terrains. I'm taking inspiration from the following article:
https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02326472/file/2019-orometry.pdf

I have contacted the authors of the project and I am allowed to use their code and modify it so that's not the problem. As the code is quite complex and uses a lot of python packages (such as numpy), I don't want to completely recode the project in the language I'm currently working with (Kotlin)

Is there any way I can use/modify the code of the project and use it as a service so that I can interact with it using a REST Api (the code would be hosted by a third-party like Heroku or something in the likes of that)? I'm not that experienced using/programming these sort of infrastructures and I don't really know where to start, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share more about the code - eg. github and the layout?

Comment: The code is available here: https://github.com/oargudo/orometry-terrains I'm not sure what you mean with layout.

Comment: Will take a look tonight. Thanks